# Could not load file or assembly when reference added

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015

I read many similar questions here, but not exactly the same, which would help me.

I have many projects in my solution and in one of them I added a reference to a project (it's already had 3 references to some other solution's project, which are working well). If I use it, everything looks correctly in VS, Resharper sees this project and there are no errors during build.

```
var activity = new Zeus.Wf.Library.BikActivity();
```

It just failed during runtime, when I use this referenced project for the first time with

> "Could not load file or assembly..."

When I look into bin folder, the dll is even there as other referenced projects, so I have no idea, what could be the problem and why it couldn't find this project.

[image]

**EDIT**

This is whole message:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Zeus.Wf.Library, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.":"Zeus.Wf.Library,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"

Comment: Does the Zeus.WF.Library have any dependencies that are not referenced? You can use ILSpy or similar to interrogate.

Comment: Please post the *full* error message. It may well have more information, such as the public key not matching the expected one. (And please put code in *text* rather than as an image.)

Comment: Is the Target Framework the same? (e.g. .Net 4 Full and .Net 4 Client Profile)

Comment: @Jon Skeet Full error message uploaded, the rest of code should be without problem I think, I just call a method on this `activity` and that's all, it fails on this uploaded row, when it tries to create instance. @Manfred Radlwimmer Target Frameworks are same, both 4.6.1

Comment: Are the DLL and utilising project compiled for the same platform, e.g. x86, Any CPU, etc?

Comment: Yes, they're both Any CPU

Comment: I didn't ask for the rest of the code, I asked you to put the code in text rather than as an image. It does sound like it might be a dependency issue, as ChrisBint suggested.